# tkinter in python align the grid at the center of the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter. I wanted to use pack() to align the components at the center of the window, but I need some rows to have 2 components, because of which I thought of using grid. Now the issue is that the components are aligned at the left side of the window. What I want is to have the items at the center of the window. I don't wanna make the components shift when I resize, so just one time fix is enough. [This is how it looks now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFEFS.png) [This is how I want it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10mVR.png)

So what I'm doing here is that after selecting the first OptionMenu, depending on the selection, I wanna show a Entry that has label with text "Pincode" or "District". And I want that Label and Entry to be on the same row.... My current code does show it the way I want, but all of it is pushed to the right. I want it all in the middle.

BTW, Indentation here is messed up, IDK how to correct it...

**EDIT:**
I've removed some bits of code that isn't necessary for the placement of the components so that you can read easily. And I've included "self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)", but then in the fetchData(), the Label() and Entry() is messed up. Entry() is on the far right side and looks like its on the 3rd column (column=2 in programmer count).

**EDIT:**
"self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)" using this, I got the output that I desired... SO this one is answered....

```
from tkinter import *


class TrackerGUI:
    def __init__(self):

    self.root = Tk()

    self.root.geometry("500x300")
    self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    OptionMenu(self.root, clicked, *options, command = self.fetchData).grid(row = 1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
    

    self.root.mainloop()


def fetchData(self, urlType):

    # Date Option Menu
    self.date = OptionMenu(self.root, datesVar, *dates).grid(row = 2, column=0, columnspan=2)

    if urlType.lower() == "pincode":
        Label(self.root, text='Pincode').grid(row=3,column=0)
    elif urlType.lower() == "district":
        Label(self.root, text='District').grid(row=3,column=0)
    
    e1 = Entry(self.root).grid(row=3,column=1)
```

Comment: Try adding: `self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Comment: aha.... this solved a part of my issue.... now what happens is that from fetchData(), the Label and e1 (Entry), those are kinda messed up... The Entry() component goes to the very right of the screen

Comment: You haven't said anything about how you want your window to look like after the entry is added so I have to guess. Try adding `self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` as well

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I'm new here... So I am learning how to ask also :-)
Anyways, this solved my problem.... So thank you soo much..........